# Count number of elements in $resource.query() object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to count the number of elements returned from `$resouce.query()` object, so that I can increment it and use it as the ID for the next object to be saved.

Following is a service to communicate with the server:

```
eventsApp.factory('EventData', function($resource) {
    var resource = $resource('/data/event/:id', {id: '@id'});
    return {
        getEvent: function(eventId) {
            return resource.get({id: eventId});
        },

        saveEvent: function(event) {
            var count = 0;
            resource.query(function(data) {
                count = data.length; // Accessible here!
            });
            event.id = count; // Not accessible here!
            return resource.save(event);

        },

        getAllEvents: function() {
            var count = 0;
            var lol = resource.query(function(data) {
                count = data.length;
            });
            console.log(count);
            return resource.query();
        }

    }
});
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, I'm unable to access the `length` property. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code what I am getting is your `resource.query` executes the callback function asynchronously because of that your `event.id = count;` is executed first and then the callback it executed. If you want to access data.length then you can use `$q` and create a defer. And then resolve that deferred object.

Comment: Could you explain how would I go about doing this in code? I'm new to AngularJS and as such, certain topics are unclear.